# Django url reverse of namespaced view in model get_absolute_url

Tags: django

I don't quite understand how I can sensically use a namespaced `reverse` lookup in a model's `get_absolute_url`. Say I have `app_name=MYAPP`in the URLConf, then I need to put `reverse('MYAPP:blah-detail ...` in the `get_absolute_url`. It seems to me that if I introduce another URLConf with a different `app_name`, the model's `get_absolute_url` would still get me the URL of MYAPP. The `app_name` cannot be imported into `model.py` either because of cyclical dependency this would create.

Is there a canonical solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to read your question a few times and I am not sure what you are asking really.

The purpose of the absolute_url is just that the absolute path to that object in the database. This is why it is normally written as a method on a model class.

If you create another app you would be using a completely different namespace and that means a different path to a different object.

If I miss understood you please let me know so I can answer it correctly.

Per your comment try this.

```
from .urls import app_name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(f'{app_name}:detail', args=[self.slug])

# or
from .apps import <AppName>Config

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(f'{<AppName>Config.name}:detail', args=[self.slug])
```

I updated the answer to the two solutions we discussed in the comments.

Comment: So I have 

    `def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('konsenser:poll-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})`

in my model where `konsenser` is my namespace, as defined by the `app_name` in `urls.py`. If I put the application somewhere else, i.e. different URLConf with different `app_name`, I'd have to change the model's `get_absolute_url` too. How do I avoid that?

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks - Problem is `from .urls import app_name`. This causes a  cyclical dependency, since `urls.py` imports views which imports models.

Comment: Now you are getting picky technically speaking you are correct but you are just getting the app name or you could do from .app import KonsenserConfig then get the app name from KonsenserConfig.name

Comment: Of course, and still: `from .urls import app_name` does not work. The `KonsenserConfig.name` advice is great. Shouldn't I then also copy that into `app_name` in `urls.py`?

Comment: You are over thinking this whole process. First off if you put this application into a new project you will need to create a new url in the main urls where you can just add the namespace. If you do not want to use the recommended approach from Django then I provided you two other methods to get the application name. The from .urls import app_name is technically not a cyclical import because your not importing everything you are just importing the value of app_name. If you are that concerned then I would import from the app.py. If that is a concern then create a new value in app.py

Comment: Thanks, it is not out of concern, `from .urls import app_name` simply throws an exception. However, I did like you mentioned and import KonsenserConfig.name from `app.py` and use that as well for `app_name` in `urls.py`. Easy enough to stay portable that way.

Comment: Cool I didn't get an exception when I called app_name. I have to look into that good luck.